# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access with JNA and OpenCV

Tags: java, c++, opencv, jna

I have an application with two parts. One part is a c++ program for opencv calculation. The other part is a Java part. I control a camera with JNA und edit the pictures from this camera with OpenCV.
I can call my function with JNA.

My Funtion in C++

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int createScript(char* imagePath)
```

In This function i call the function

```
void BladeCutter::calcMeanValues(cv::Mat image)
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> bgr_planes;
    cv::split(image, bgr_planes);
    cv::Scalar blue = cv::mean(bgr_planes[0]);
    cv::Scalar green = cv::mean(bgr_planes[1]);
    cv::Scalar red = cv::mean(bgr_planes[2]);
    meanValues.scalar = cv::Scalar(blue[0], green[0], red[0]);
    meanValues.brightness = calcBrightness(image);
}
```

and get a Invalid memory access at cv::split(image, bgr_planes);
If i call the program without jna the program works fine.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
  at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
  at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:477)
  at com.sun.jna.Function.invokeString(Function.java:658)
  at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:402)
  at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:323)
  at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:236)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.createScript(Unknown Source)
  at de.test.BladeTileLocator.main(BladeTileLocator.java:14)
```

BladeTileLocator is the Java-Class.

```
package de.test;

import com.sun.jna.Native;

import de.interfaces.IBladeTileLocator;

public class BladeTileLocator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final byte[] ba = new byte[50];
        final IBladeTileLocator bladeTileLocator = (IBladeTileLocator) Native.loadLibrary("BladeTileLocator", IBladeTileLocator.class);
        final String path = "C:\\Users\\bak\\Pictures\\Bildanalyse\\Bild.JPG";
        bladeTileLocator.createScript(path);
    }
}
```

My JNA Interface to call the function:

```
package de.interfaces;

import com.sun.jna.Library;

public interface IBladeTileLocator extends Library {
    int createScript(String imagePath);
}
```

Comment: I use the table on the site https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md to know which types i can use. char* is in jna string.

Comment: The mapping is correct.  You should focus your attention on what about the JVM execution environment is different from your C environment.  When you call the function "without JNA", are you invoking it as a shared library or linking directly to the code?  You may be inadvertently referencing some uninitialized global or static state.

Comment: Try adding a line after your last line in `main` referencing the string `path`.  It might be possible that an aggressive GC might be disposing of the `String` before the callee gets to it.

Comment: Further in my code i call many opencv functions like cv::imread, cv::findContours, cv::drawContours. I dont know why cv::split throws this kind of exception. I post tomorrow my whole code.

Comment: You could turn off `jna.protected` and let the JVM core dump.  That might give you a bit of a native stack which might provide some insight.

Comment: I set jna.protected to false and got this  message
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b18) (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.66-b18 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [opencv_world300.dll+0xb0fbfe]
But I use the opencv_world300.dll before. Only the split method throws this kind of exception.

Comment: I found the problem. In my project properties of my dll i had this kind of additional libraries
opencv_ts300.lib
opencv_ts300d.lib
I deleted the release versions and know i works fine.
opencv_world300.lib
opencv_world300d.lib
But why is java using the release lib and why can i execute some methods and others not?

Comment: Most likely it's a difference in `PATH`.  That gets copied into `java.library.path` (along with some other things) by the JVM.   Your IDE might modify it additionally, so it's best to check that there are no differences between direct JVM invocation, IDE invocation, and native code invocation.